# I need to open some files in a folder that contains "RPA" in their name. so how can I do that in automation anywhere?

Tags: automationanywhere

I am creating a program that opens files in a folder that contains "RPA" in their name. so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You will use **Loop on File in Folder** command, and if condition inside the loop to check if the file name includes RPA.

```
Loop on Files on Folder   
   If condition $Filename$ includes RPA  
      Do Something here eg. open program/file command  
   End If   
End Loop
```

[image]

Comment: I am totally new on it. So, Don't know how to choose the 2nd command. Can you please elaborate how can I do this.

Comment: Ok done. But getting error unable to open the file as source file does not exist.

Comment: source file does not exist is resolved. but don't know how it should only open one file at a time and after doing some operation on its move to the next file

Comment: You will put the action that you want to perform after opening the file, What are you trying to do?

Comment: let me explain to you what I want to do exactly? I want to create a bot that opens a specific folder and open file names including "RPA" and then copy its content to a new word file and then save that word file and then move to next file which includes "RPA" keyword in Filename and then do the same operation and then move to next.

Comment: or it will be beneficial if I can convert all filenames(already in pdf) including "RPA" to word files and save it in a different folder.

Answer (score 1):

@Shivam,

To get more clarity on your problem statement, you mentioned once that the files are already in PDF.
Are you trying to copy content from PDF to Word? In that case, you could use [PDF Integration commands](https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/enterprise/topics/aae-client/bot-creator/commands/pdf-integration-command.html), provided the PDFs are not hand-written or scans. If that is the case, the text extraction might become more unreliable.
A safe bet with Automation Anywhere is to just extract all the text, open a new Word document and paste the content and save file.
Saving all files as word might a little counter-intuitive. You can just use the If statement within your for loop to only process files with "RPA" in their name.

Hope this help. Let us know you go :-)

Answer (score 0):

its pretty simple use includes in your if statement
[workbench snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TIQh.png)